i have Seen error how to handel this error in flutter please resolved it

how to handel please resoved this error.I am facing some I need..................
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_vibrate:parseDebugLocalResources'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_vibrate:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
> zip END header not found


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you share the pubspec.yml file. I can find the package that is using the flutter_vibrate package

I think you used flutter_vibrate package in your flutter app. But you know it's been 2 year since it is updated. So there might be some version compatibility issue. Try to remove this package and comment its relevant code in your app. Then build the app. If its works then you need to find replacement for this package
